# BIOS boot screen on restart with Thinkpad E485 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 18.04.1 up and running on a Thinkpad E485. The computer has two drives installed. An M.2 SSD (boot) and a SATA HDD (data). I've added the kernel parameter ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 to get it to boot (thanks to Evil Azrael), and most things seem to work now.

An issue I have is whenever I restart the computer, it comes back up with the BIOS boot screen [Boot Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoIQf.jpg). FYI, the Toshiba is the HDD data disk.  No matter what you select on the boot screen, it immediately pops back up.  As a result, I have to hold the switch and power off.

I tried a lot of things before I realized this does **not** happen if I select shutdown in Ubuntu vs. restart. This is my workaround, but if others have had/resolved such an issue, I'd be interested in knowing how.  Some things I learned/tried along the way:

1. Currently booting UEFI with Smartboot enabled (but tried disabling and same thing)
2. Tried legacy/MBR and similar issue.
3. W10 alone has no such issue.
4. W10 dual booted with Ubuntu also has no such issue, but again Ubuntu does.
5. Tried Ubuntu installed and booting from the HDD disk and same issue.

Again, what I have now works but it's annoying - as a noob I restart the computer a lot :-)  Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add these parameters to the kernel line in grub

```
ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1 spec_store_bypass_disable=seccomp
```

on my system it's in /etc/default/grub and the whole line looks like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1 spec_store_bypass_disable=seccomp idle=nomwait"
```

I found this information [here](https://evilazrael.de/node/401) - the author eventually sold his E485, which I am on the verge of doing as well.

Comment: I was just able to upgrade to kernel 4.20.7 using UKUU by adding an additional parameter - iommu=soft

Comment: Thanks!  After upgrading the kernel from 4.15 to 4.20 this did the trick.

Comment: With my current kernel, 5.1.16-050116-generic, I was able to remove the parameter amd_iommu=on, leaving just iommu=soft.

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu 19.04 (Linux Kernel 5.0)**, the following parameters made the ThinkPad boot:

```
ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1
```

and black screen on resume from suspend/sleep with closed lid could be solved with

```
iommu=pt
```

These parmeters are applied in `/etc/default/grub` in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable and set via

```
sudo update-grub
```